# When I try to attach xsd to xml, root of xml become red(in Intellij IDEA), what problem it can be?

Tags: xml, xsd

I attach xsd to xml:

```
<product name="example" version="example" xmlns:msi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamecpaceLocation="product.xsd">
```

But product don't see the schema, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
xsi:noNamecpaceLocation
```

be

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
```

and

```
xmlns:msi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

be

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```